# How to write the coset for the following quotient group

Tags: group-theory, notation

I would like to know for the following question,
Let $E$ be the group of even integers and $N$ the subgroup of all multiples of 8.

The cosets for the quotient group $E/N$, mathematical  notation can be written as
$$
Ea = \{a \pmod 8 \mid \forall a\in 2t,\, t\in Z\}. 
$$
Is that correct?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: use `\mid` for the "such that" bar with proper spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $aN = \{ an\mid n\in N\}$ with $a\in E$. Cosets are $N, 2N, 4N, 6N$.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Comment: @SethMai, mark that the question is answered if you're satisfied.

Comment: @SammyBlack I just did.  For some reason, the site told me I have to wait 7 minutes to be able to do so.  I am not sure what happened.

Comment: Ohhhh... gotcha.